# Docker connection issue - connection timeout

Tags: docker

I was following along with Docker tutorial over here: https://docs.docker.com/mac/step_three/

I am able to run the `docker run hello-world` implying the initial set up in working.

I tried `docker search whalesay` but get this error

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/search?q=whalesay: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 192.168.0.1:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:58317->192.168.0.1:53: i/o timeout
```

Running `docker pull hello-world` gives this output

```
Using default tag: latest
Pulling repository docker.io/library/hello-world
Network timed out while trying to connect to https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/hello-world/images. You may want to check your internet connection or if you are behind a proxy.
```

Running `curl -v https://index.docker.io:443` gives this output

```
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7f9c01002200
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7f9c01002200) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to index.docker.io port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 52.72.231.247...
* Connected to index.docker.io (52.72.231.247) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
* Server certificate: *.docker.io
* Server certificate: RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3
* Server certificate: GeoTrust Global CA
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: index.docker.io
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
* Server nginx/1.6.2 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.6.2
< Date: Fri, 25 Mar 2016 11:19:56 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Location: https://registry.hub.docker.com/
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
<
* Connection #0 to host index.docker.io left intact
```

I am not sure what's the issue here. Any network settings I need to look into?

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @VonC I am not sure. How do I check?

Comment: @VonC I tried http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test, it says I am not behind a proxy

Comment: Are you on Windows or Mac?

Comment: @VonC on a Mac, tried this http://whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-check It says "Proxy server detected"

Comment: Are you in a docker-machine session? Did you do a docker-machine ssh?

Comment: @VonC No, did not do a docker-machine ssh.

Comment: Try the same tutorial within a docker-machine ssh session.